# MS Word 2013 Disable Template Saving

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

In MS Word 2013, when I create a new document with a personal template, whenever I wish to save the document, Word prompts me to save changes to the template as well. How can I disable this prompt?

Note: I ***DO NOT*** wish to save the changes to the template.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the actual steps I had to follow in order to complete this. I used the above mentioned options as well as help from other forums to figure this out. I am using Office 2013.

1. You must open Word as administrator.
2. To do this, right click on your Microsoft Office Word 2013 shortcut and select properties(If you're clicking on a task bar shortcut you will need to right click on the task bar icon, then right click on the Word 2013 shortcut right above the task bar).
3. From the properties menu click Open File Location.
4. From the \root\office15 directory, right click on winword.exe and select Run as administrator
5. Go to File > Options > Add-Ins
6. At the bottom, click the Go... button right next to the COM Add-ins drop down menu.
7. Remove the check from the Send to Bluetooth Add-Ins box.
8. Click OK

Now you should be able to open and work on any template file without being asked to save changes to your original template. I discovered that the Bluetooth plugin has been faulty for at least a year or two now by reference over at [this article](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/2574-disable-do-you-also-want-save-changes-2.html), however there's no reference to where they found that information... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have just been searching for this very same thing and found the solution as follows:

In Word, go to `Options > Add-Ins`, click the `Go` button next to `Manage COM Add-ins`.

Disable the `Add-ins` and this will fix the problem.